# return count value to view laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to count the amount of emails in my table and return it to my view.

Controller

```
    $data = DB::table('users')->count('email');
    return view('home', compact('data', $data));
```

View

```
echo $data;
```

OR

```
{{$data}}
```

OR

```
return $data->email;
```

Nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
return view('home', compact('data'));
```

This is correct syntax for [`compact()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function.